# How to index numbers and floats in elastic search using node.js but not as strings

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to index integers as integers only using node.js code how to specify it in schema for ex- for string we write

FirstName: { type: String, 
            es_indexed: true
           },

Answer (score 0):

You need to post a mapping look at [mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html)